# playwright get click target

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

is it possible to get the target on click?
for example, I have the following code:

```
await page.mouse.click(200, 200)
```

and in this position I have an input, is it possible to get the target in this clicked position and find out that there is a input there?

Comment: Is there any reason you rather click the position instead of the input itself?

Comment: @innis just for learning :)

Comment: I can't think in any way to do this rather than set an variable and the set an event listener for each one of your inputs and then define the previously declared variable with the value you want to set when you click.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the coordinates to the `document.elementFromPoint` method ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)). Since this method is in the web page context, we will use `page.evaluate` in the Playwright API.

```js
await page.evaluate(([x, y]) => {
  const element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  return element instanceof HTMLInputElement;
}, [200, 200])
```

The x, y values in the `page.mouse.click` are relative to the top-left corner of the viewport, which is what the `elementFromPoint` API expects.

Comment: This works to some extent. Since the page execution context is different than the test execution context, the returned object is a serialized version of the DOM element. The serialized object does not retain a handle that is usable within the playwright test context. For example, the test code cannot click() on the element returned from evaluate().  

There is an open issue in the playwright repo to fix this by implementing a a page locator() that takes x,y as input. Needs more upvotes.